# Code::Blocks MPICH2 Undefined reference in Windows

Tags: windows, mingw, mpi, codeblocks, mpich

I searched on how to link MPICH2 to Code::Blocks, but couldn't find an understandable solution. (running windows 7 64x bit)

So what I did so far is I downloaded the MPICH2 from windows market,
then I install both the `.msi` and the `.exe`.

The mpi didn't functions, so I tried using the link and tools section inside code::blocks. No go.

So I copied the `.h` and `.lib` files into the MinGW path and choose the 32x bit files to put in the lib folder because both the MinGW is in the 32x program files and the Target PC that will upload the code into is 32x. (I tried the 64x later, no difference).

So far thats the most optimal thing I did the `Code::blocks` now complete the syntax and tell me whats the parameters is. It just had a problem with `sal.h`, so I downloaded that and put it in the header and now only give me errors when ever I use the misodes as in

Example:

if I use `MPI_Init(NULL,NULL);`,
my console outputs `undefined reference to`MPI_Init@8'|`

My problem is a particular one and most search results was about either one aspect. So I don't know what to do next.

Keep in mind I am a student and have minimum experience in IDE, Compilers, linkers and programming in general. I am in your care.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5141042/setting-code-block-to-run-mpich2

Answer (score 0):

Thank you , you just edit my grammar while I was trying to fix my own problem all by myself .

I did it thanks for the help "not" .

so I think the linker and lib didnt sync up automatically when I copied it to the MGW file "weird even thou it was completing the syntax and refused to run when I sent false parameters" so basicly I did .

setting >> compiler.. >> Linker setting > add > "the mpi or msmpi lib dir keep in mind 86x or 64x" .

setting >> compiler.. >> Search Dirctory > add > "the Include dir keep in mind 86x or 64x" .

and thats basicly it it runs now but it doesn't use more than one core "my pc is an i3" so I will update it after I fix that .